# How to replace smilies in text such as :) with an image?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to show smilies as images in my JSF/PrimeFaces web application. For this I would need to replace text like `:)` with an image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: not sure how JSF works but if you can create ServletFilter maybe you could that there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF doesn't offer any facilities for this.

At its simplest, you could just use [the available methods of the `String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to perform manipulations on a `String` instance, such as [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
text = text.replace(":)", "<img src=\"smile.png\" />");
```

*(you might want to apply more finer-grained matching, perhaps with regex or a lexer, to prevent that legit character sequences such as* "... a semicolon ; (or a colon, :) ..." *are incorrectly been replaced)*

Then, to present the manipulated `String` instance with HTML images in it in JSF, you'd need to use `<h:outputText>` with the `escape` attribute set to `false` to disable the builtin HTML-escaping which is been used to prevent XSS attack holes.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
```

This way the HTML `<img>` element will be literally interpreted by the webbrowser instead of being displayed plaintext to the enduser due to the escaping.

But, as you might already have guessed, this puts of course possible [XSS attack holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) open if you don't sanitize the enduser's input beforehand. The enduser would be able to do bad things with input such as adding a `<script>stealCookies()</script>` to the text which would be literally interpreted by the webbrowser as well. To sanitize enduser's input beforehand, you can use among others [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) which offers a [`clean()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) method for this:

```
text = Jsoup.clean(text, Whitelist.basic());
```

*(do this before replacing the smilies, or it might strip off those `<img>` tags as well!)*